# Antlr installment issue in Eclipse

Tags: antlr

I install antlr in my eclipse. And set antlr-code generator-output folder-project relative folder as antlr-generator.

I can new grammar file (grammar.g)and compile it successfully. 
There isn't files in the folder (antlr-generator)
But files:
grammarLexer.java and grammarParser.java are not created.

How can fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just installed Eclipse Indigo and ANTLR 3.4 on Windows 7x64 and had the same problem and no errors on the ANTLR Console. Uninstalled java and installed latest v7 update 4 (32 and 64 bit) and cleaned up classpath and path environment variables. Still no files generated but now I was seeing error "No such directory: org/antlr/tool/templates/dot/dfa" in the ANTLR Console. The fix is in Eclipse under Window, Preferences, ANTLR, Builder, Building. In the General section, make sure that -nfa and -dfa are **unchecked**. This fixed it for me.

I am not an expert programmer and have yet to write an ANTLR program. Probably others here can figure out how to fix the directory not found error.

I ended up creating [this article on configuring ANTLR IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8343488/antlr-ide-in-eclipse-doesnt-work/10887515#10887515) in case you never go this working or just wanted to check your configuration. And [this article on testing/debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10838068/testing-antlr-grammar/10886842#10886842) may be helpful also.

Comment: Did you find an answer? Was this helpful?