# ANTLR myParser.java not generated

Tags: java, eclipse, antlr

Do you have any idea why my parser is not generated when I create an empty grammar? (and yes I have saved the file)

I wish to integrate antlr in Eclipse. I installed Eclipse indigo 3.7, the required updates (GEF 3.2, ZEST 1.3, DLTK 3.0), then installed the antlr IDE plugin v2.1.2 and antlr3.4.

When putting everything together I realised that no .java files(lexer/parser) was generated from my defined grammar (combined/ lexer+parser).

It definitely has nothing to do with the grammar code itself.. it must be a mistake in the setting up or an annoying bug.

Running Eclipse indigo 3.7
Antlr 3.4

-------FIXED NOW------------
I definitely had a working grammar. I managed to fix it by using an older version. (antlr 3.2 and eclipse 3.5.1)

Comment: Is your grammar correct, no left recursion...., if yes then try to use an older version of ANTLR, 3.3 maybe.

Answer (score 0):

This does work with Indigo, IDE 2.1.2, and antlr 3.4 if the configuration is right. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8343488/antlr-ide-in-eclipse-doesnt-work).