# ANTLR Grammar file Editor for Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, antlr3

Recently I tried to write ANTLR grammar file (.g) using the ANTLR Editor for eclipse available at http://antlreclipse.sourceforge.net/updates/.

I found this editor to be useful only for highlighting the syntax (unless I always keep compiling manually).

Is there any eclipse based ANTLR editor equivalent to ANTLR Works and compatible with ANTLR 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [AntrDT](http://www.certiv.net/projects/antlrdt.html) also [recommended](https://theantlrguy.atlassian.net/wiki/plugins/servlet/mobile?contentId=2687335#IntegrationwithDevelopmentEnvironments-Eclipse3.3+forAntlr3.x) on Antlr3 web site.
For Antlr4 there is also [antlr4ide](https://github.com/jknack/antlr4ide).

Comment: Wow...Perfect! This is exactly what I wanted to do. Thank you.

Comment: As [XText](http://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/) is gaining a rapid acceptance as DSL writer, I was curious whether it provides editor for developing ANTLR grammers as well.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using ANTLR in Eclipse for about six weeks now. It works quite well once you get the process down. You **definitely** shouldn't have to compile manually so check your [ANTLR IDE configuration here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8343488/antlr-ide-in-eclipse-doesnt-work/10887515#10887515). If that's all good, then take a look at [the ANTLR test/debug process in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10838068/testing-antlr-grammar/10886842#10886842). Hope these help.

Comment: AntlrDT looks like a more comprehensive editor than what's in the ANTLR IDE and I certainly like the AST viewer. But per their website it's version-specific to v3.2 so using v3.4 and string templates v4 is out. I plan on doing some testing and will report back.

Comment: Yes @cb4 AntlrDT seems more comprehensive...For v3.4 we can depend on ANTLRWorks till your test results :-) above links for ANTLR IDE will be useful in case V4 is the limitation for AntlrDT. Thanks!

Comment: I did manage to get some parts of AntlrDT working in Indigo after a few hours of fiddling with Eclipse plug-in locations and different versions of required components. The editor works and ANTLRWorks can be run by right-clicking a .g file so you could use it that way. I got no farther - the AntlrDT launcher always errors out. Too bad they don't keep it updated or release the source... Looks like the ANTLR IDE is your best bet. It makes for a very usable and fully functional environment with latest Eclipse, Java7, and graphviz for viewing antlr ASTs.